# Why can't my maven find the stripe library?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

Using intellij I can see the package in my External Libraries, but when I build using maven I get the below issue:

When running:

```
mvn clean package
```

I get this error:

```
Failure to find com.stripe:stripe-java:jar:${stripe-version} in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
```

Where the version is:

```
<stripe-version>1.1.16</stripe-version>
```

I tried 1.1.13 and 1.1.14 also and I get the same error.

When running with -e switch I get:

```
Failure to find com.stripe:stripe-java:jar:${stripe-version} in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:170)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:171)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: Failure to find com.stripe:stripe-java:jar:${stripe-version} in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:412)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:164)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to find com.stripe:stripe-java:jar:${stripe-version} in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:541)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:220)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:395)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Failure to find com.stripe:stripe-java:jar:${stripe-version} in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.checkArtifact(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:190)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:430)
    ... 26 more
```

I can see the versions here: http://search.maven.org/#browse%7C788949441

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dependency downloads just fine:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.stripe</groupId>
    <artifactId>stripe-java</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.16</version>
</dependency>
```

Seems like you have a problem defining / using the stripe version property:

```
<properties>
    <stripe.version>1.1.16</stripe.version>
</properties>

<!--- ... -->
<version>${stripe.version}</version>
```

Comment: I have this: `<dependency>
            <groupId>com.stripe</groupId>
            <artifactId>stripe-java</artifactId>
            <version>${stripe-version}</version>
        </dependency>`

Comment: Try with `<version>1.1.16</version>`, if it fixes your problem then try the property in the way that that I've described above.

Comment: it worked, not sure why though as I define all my versions the same way!

Comment: when I did ${stripe.version} I get this now: Could not find artifact com.stripe:stripe-java:jar:${stripe.version} in central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2) ->

Comment: Did you open and close the tags correctely? `<stripe.version>1.1.16</stripe.version>` how about the rest of your version properties?

Comment: Yes, intellij downloads it fine: ` <aws-version>1.3.27</aws-version>
        <joda-version>2.1</joda-version>

        <stripe-version>1.1.16</stripe-version>`

Comment: I tried the . and it didn't work, and my property definitions are in the parent pom, and the usage is in a module.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24605/discussion-between-anthony-accioly-and-blankman)

Comment: yes it worked when I defined the property in the same pom, so your right it doesn't seem to be picking up the parent pom correctly.  Running 'mvn clean install' in the parent pom worked thanks!